# Как работать с полем типа Array в Doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, doctrine2

Имеется , пока пустое, поле в таблице(сущности)

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="options", type="array", nullable=true, unique=false)
 */
private $options;


/**
 * Set options
 *
 * @param array $options
 *
 * @return Config
 */
public function setOptions($options)
{
    $this->options = $options;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get options
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getOptions()
{
    return $this->options;
}
```

при выборе поля

```
$record = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Config::class)->findOneBy(['...' => '...']);
```

получаю

Could not convert database value "" to Doctrine Type array

Подскажите как работать через Doctrine с такими полями (выборка, сохранение и т.д.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поля типа `array` Doctrine хранит в базе в виде массива, сконвертированного функцией `serialize()`. Делать выборку по отдельно взятому элементу массива — не самый правильный путь. Но если вам нужно сравнить массивы целиком, то вот:

```
$arr = array(); // Массив для сравнения
$record = $this
  ->entityManager
  ->getRepository(Config::class)
  ->findOneBy(['options' => $arr]);
```

То есть, при формировании запроса в конструкторе вам нужно предоставлять ему данные для полей в том виде, в котором они объявлены. Если поле является массивом, конструктор запросов не примет ничего, кроме массива.

Comment: Делать выборку по отдельно взятому элементу массива не планируется. Необходимо выбрать всё поле, т.е. массив, и работать с ним как с массивом, напр., найти в нем данные под ключом 'test', заменить значение, и снова сохранить в БД. Не подскажите как это реализовывается?

Comment: @Drakulitka, В приведенном выше примере произойдет такая выборка: `SELECT * FROM название_таблицы t WHERE t.options = "a:0:{}" LIMIT 1`, после чего, если такая строка будет найдена, массив можно будет получить методом `$record->getOptions()`

Comment: Почему же тогда выбрасывается ошибка если поле пустое?
'Could not convert database value "" to Doctrine Type array'
Разве не должен вернуться empty[] ?

Comment: Ошибки не будет, если вместо `""` передавать `null`.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло ))